# Talking and Mentioning Allah in Public Bathrooms

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sunnah

Al Salam Alaykum, I have read/heard before that one should not talk in bathrooms and especially not mention Allah.

**Can anyone let me know if talking and mentioning Allah at the sinks area in public bathrooms is halal, haram, or makruh?** Also, if silence is the right thing, how should I handle situations when I'm approached, or if I have to talk and the conversations calls for "inshaAllah" or the person infornt of me says Allah in one way or another.

The reason I'm unsure is that toilet cubicles are "enclosed". But there are urinals in the same space as the sinks, so it's up in the air to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

walaykum salam

Here are some sites that say mentioning Allah's name in the bathroom is offensive and shouldn't be done. hence to be silent whilst relieving yourself is the best thing to do.

https://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/34010 - shouldnt mention Allah's name in the bathroom
http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2018/12/01/speaking-bathroom/

If you're approached try your best to get around saying Allah's name - use alternative words.

May Allah grant us knowledge and action. Ameen.